# How to fix pycharm installation with 3.7.2 using a code import

Tags: python, pycharm

so i will rewrite this question. I have installed Pycharm and Python 3.7.2 and wanted to import a programm that is running flawless on another pc from a friend. when i try to start a .py programmpart i get this message, no matter what code it is. it could be as easy as this:

```
print ("Hello World")

enter code here"C:\Users\****\PycharmProjects\Python RPG\venv\Scripts\python.exe"` "C:/Users/****/PycharmProjects/Python RPG/Tag 5 - 2 - Changing Pictures.py"
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\****\PycharmProjects\Python RPG\venv\lib\site.py", line 703, in <module>
        main()
      File "C:\Users\****\PycharmProjects\Python RPG\venv\lib\site.py", line 692, in main
        aliasmbcs()
      File "C:\Users\****\PycharmProjects\Python RPG\venv\lib\site.py", line 515, in aliasmbcs
        import locale, codecs
      File "C:\Users\****\PycharmProjects\Python RPG\venv\lib\locale.py", line 19, in <module>
        import functools
    ImportError: No module named functools

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

interesting thing is: at my friends computer the code is even executed when written like this:

```
    print "hello world"
```

it seems some kind of toolset is missing. Maybe this pillow or pi. As you can see: in this first snippet of code i don't need any functions, but later on i do:

```
import Image, ImageTk   #Necesary to display pictures
import Tkinter

root = Tkinter.Tk()
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Cat.jpg"))
panel = Tkinter.Label(root, image = img)
panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")

root.mainloop()
```

what you can't see here is that pycharm underlays import, and imagetk with a red line, saying this functions are not known.

Comment: `Image` is not a built-in module. You have to install either Pillow or PIL.

Comment: Please show one example of code and the error you get when trying to run that snippet. You mention a lot of things in your question, but it is a bit confusing; it is harder to help you if we don't understand your problem.

Comment: OK so without pillow or pil i cant run functions? I will show you an example. Have to copy a few bits and will put Thema here later this day.

Comment: coming clother to a solution. the code my friend send me is in python 2. there seems to be a conflict with python 3 as some statements are changed to functions.

Answer (score 0):

ok,
i found out what the problem was. my friend used a 32x environment and python 2.7 while i installed a 64x environment and python 3.x. he didn't say which requirements he set.

this led to many errors and i couldn't use the simplest code snippet he sent. 
i deinstalled python and installed 2.7 with 32x.

Now all the tools are able to use and all the functions work.